How to reliably send non transactional kafka messages using spring kafka
Starting with kafka 3.0 we get strongest delivery guarantees by default (acks=all, enable.idempotence=true) ( https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-3-0-major-improvements-and-new-features/ )
Knowing that I am am not sure about:

for non transactional producer, is it enough to send messages as ? :

kafkaTemplate.send("my_topic", "my value");
or do I need to do ?:
kafkaTemplate.send("my_topic", "my value").get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
in order to reliably ensure that my message reached the broker

By calling get(), you're making a blocking call. Has nothing to do with transactions or ensuring the record has been written. You can still add a producer callback to the first method to make it non blocking
